# Cannot get indexOf() from array

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexof

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to do this project for my class however I've been stuck for the last hour on one single part. I'm trying to call the index of the variables under the "fromCity" array, however the all come back as "-1". I'm not sure why it is doing this because in the second array "toCity" I am having no issues in getting the index. Thank you for the help.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

    public class EX07_2 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           ArrayList<String> fromCity = new ArrayList<>();
                Arrays.asList("Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Portland");

            String[] toCity;
            toCity = new String[3];
            toCity[0] = "Seattle";
            toCity[1] = "Denver";
            toCity[2] = "Chicago";

            int [][] distance = new int[3][3];
            distance [0][0] = 1135;
            distance [0][1] = 1016;
            distance [0][2] = 2015;
            distance [1][0] = 807;
            distance [1][1] = 1250;
            distance [1][2] = 2128;
            distance [2][0] = 174;
            distance [2][1] = 1240;
            distance [2][2] = 2121;


            System.out.println("Enter the name of a city to travel from: ");
            String city1 = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the name of a city to travel to: ");
            String city2 = scanner.nextLine();
            int index1 = asList(fromCity).indexOf(city1);
            int index2 = asList(toCity).indexOf(city2);

            System.out.println(distance[index1][index2]);




        }
    }
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns a `List` object. But you neglected to capture that `List`, so it went to garbage collection.

Comment: `fromCity` does not contain any items. It's empty. Additionally, `asList(fromList)` gives you a `List<ArrayList<String>>` which will not contain a string (it contains lists) – your IDE should show you at least two warnings for that code. Read and understand the warnings

Comment: `Arrays.asList` can still be changed. `List.of` creates an immutable list, `Arrays.asList` does not (you can still change items, sort the list, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that your `fromCity` is empty as the result of `Arrays.asList` is not assigned to `fromCity`. The indentation of your code is somehow misleading here, as one can be tricked into thinking this is a chained call, but it is not.

Also, as `fromCity` is already an `ArrayList` using `asList(fromCity)` is rather pointless and you you can get the index directly by `fromCity.indexOf(city1)`.

BTW: you will face `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if either city is not found because you don't check if index is `-1` prior using it.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure everything out and get it to run the way I wanted, appreciate the help.